# Want to connect to a local site hosted in IIS from the emulator, not localhost though

Tags: asp.net, iis, networking, android-emulator, mobile-website

I want to access www.example.com locally hosted site in IIS. Added entry in host file for mapping www.example.com to 127.0.0.1. Not able to access it using Android emulator.

Tried 10.0.2.2 as well in emulator. `http://10.0.2.2` this address is accessing the default website of IIS. But not able to access newly added site www.example.com. Working fine for desktop browsers.

Comment: try to map `www.example.com` to `10.0.2.2`, and also add on IIS the correct binding

Answer (score -1):

You can use secure tunnel to make your local ip say "http://10.0.2.2" online.You can use
[Ngrok](https://ngrok.com/)
It makes your ip/(site posted on that local ip) avalible online so that you'd be able to access your site online